# "Unrecognized file" when I try to open it C++

Tags: c++, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans 8.2 and I am programming with C++.
I'm trying to read a file. I have put it in the correct project folder of sources and I have used `#include <fstream>` .

```
ifstream myfile ("figures.txt"); 
code...
myfile.close();
```

I have the file in the correct place. But this message pops up:

[image: ERROR IN FILES]

**Unrecognized file**

Then, my other part of code also gives me error, because never detects the file I'm talking about open.

```
if (myfile.is_open()){
code...
}else{ 
cout << "file not open" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the file is not in the right place.  Typically it will be where the source files are or where the executable is.

Comment: I have copied the disk direction of  `nbproject` and created it there. I think I have done it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto solved, the .txt must be in the project folder, not in nbproject folder. At least it has worked doing it this way. Any more reccomendations will be accepted!

Comment: In the future just write `ofstream myfile ("afasfsafasfcxc.txt"); ` and see where it gets saved.

Comment: @GRC yes of course, I must wait tomorrow anyway haha